# Received exception while creating connection for pool. IO Error: Unknown host specified in weblogic server

Tags: database, jdbc, weblogic

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified

Comment: what could be the possible reason for this issue, after restart the connection pool is working fine and application connects to the database.

Comment: <Received exception while creating connection for pool "connectionpool": IO Error: Unknown host specified .><BEA-001156> <Stack trace associated with message 001129 follows: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Unknown host specified